# Javascript - How to change focus on links in a list with keyboard arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, focus

I'm able to change focus when the links are not wrapped in other elements.

This works:

HTML

```
<a id="first" href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
<a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
<a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
```

JS (with jQuery)

```
$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        // Down key
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
            $(".move:focus").next().focus();       
        }

        // Up key
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {      
            $(".move:focus").prev().focus();       
        }
    }
);
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/WWQPR)

But how do I achieve the same thing when the links are inside a list for example? Like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="first" href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .closest() to find the parent element then use .next() to get the next li, then use .find() to get the next .move

```
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
        $(".move:focus").closest('li').next().find('a.move').focus();   
    }

    // Up key
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {      
        $(".move:focus").closest('li').prev().find('a.move').focus();   
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WWQPR/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
  $(".move:focus").parent().next().find('a').focus();   
}
if (e.keyCode == 38) {      
  $(".move:focus").parent().prev().find('a').focus();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to want your focus to cycle when reaching the end of the list, you can do something like this:

```
var $li = $('li'),

$move = $(".move").click(function () {
    this.focus();
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) {
        var inc = e.keyCode == 40 ? 1 : -1,
            move = $move.filter(":focus").parent('li').index() + inc;
        $li.eq(move % $li.length).find('.move').focus();
    }
});

$move.filter(':first').focus();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WWQPR/5/